# Integral involving power of logarithm

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I was wondering if we can compute the following integral:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}{e^{\alpha y} y^{\beta} (\ln y)^m {\rm d}y} $$

where $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\alpha > 0$, $\beta>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the series expansion for $e^x$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^1y^\beta \ln^m y \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha y)^k}{k!}\,dy\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{y^\beta \ln^m y (\alpha y)^k}{k!}\,dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1 \frac{y^\beta \ln^m y (\alpha y)^k}{k!}\,dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{i \pi  m} \alpha^k m! (\beta+k+1)^{-m-1}}{k!}\\
&= (-1)^m m!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^k}{k!}(\beta+k+1)^{-m-1}\\
&=\frac{m!(-1)^m}{(\beta+1)^{m+1}} \, _{m+1}F_{m+1}(\beta+1,\beta+1,\dots, \beta+1;\beta+2,\beta+2,\dots, \beta+2;\alpha)\\
\end{align}$$

I'm not very familiar with hypergeometrics and you may be able to simplify it further.

Comment: Thanks Ben Longo. Is there a way to compute the infinite series instead of using the hypergeometric function notation?

Comment: @kagami For some special cases of $a$, $b$ and $k$ there are closed forms. Even the case $a=1, b=2, m=2$ results in having to calculate the sum 

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2n!}$$

which doesn't have a known closed form. I think that is the best way to write it in general.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The classical reference "Table of Integrals, Series and Products" by Gradshtein and Ryzhnik (Academic Press 2nd printing, 1981) contains this formula :

(4.358)  $\int_1^{\infty}x^{\nu-1}e^{-\mu x}(ln(x))^m dx=\dfrac{d^m}{d\nu^m}[\mu^{-\nu}\Gamma(\mu,\nu)] \ ,  m=0,1..., Re \mu >0, Re \nu >0.$

A further change of variable X=1/x is needed to get the appropriate bounds of integration.

(Such integrals are usually computed by complex integration and/or derivation with respect to a parameter under the integration symbol).

Comment: Is this still equivalent after the change in variable?

Comment: The problem is that doing the change of variable you've mentioned, we will have $e^{-\frac{\mu}{X}}$ which is different from the form of the integral I want to compute.